# how to use a type for the response from axios.get

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I have a simple code to fetch data via Axios:

```
const response= await axios.get("blabla");
```

and now I'm trying to use typescript.

When I add the type to the get method it works:

```
const response= await axios.get<Todo[]>("blabla");
```

but what i need is something like:

```
const response:Todo[] = await axios.get("blabla");
```

but if i do that i get an error on `response.data` saying: *Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Todo[]'*

so 2 questions:
1) why didn't it happen for the first approach?
2) how to do the second way?

Comment: `response` is not of type `Todo[]`. Do it like this instead:
`const response: Todo[] = (await axios.get(...)).data`

Comment: @dziraf  did what you said and still have the same issue

Comment: are you sure that whatever BE is returning is exactly a list of `Todo`?

Comment: yes I am 100% sure

Comment: @rickdenhaan  could you please post a complete answer with code in it? thanks indeed for your help

Comment: @farmcommand yeah I thought it would be a better fit as an answer than as a comment :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`axios.get()` returns an `AxiosResponse<any>` object, where `response.data` is `any`.

`axios.get<Todo[]>()` returns an `AxiosResponse<Todo[]>` object, where `response.data` is `Todo[]`.

So you can type `response` as:

```
const response: AxiosResponse<Todo[]> = await axios.get("blabla");
```

Comment: What about `response.page`, `response.status` ? It won't be typed this way. I made it work only this way: `http.get<Breweries[], responseData<Breweries[]>>('/breweries')` but looks too verbose.

Comment: @AlexanderKim Are you using Axios? An Axios response object [does not have](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) a `.page` attribute.

Comment: Yes, indeed, sorry, i was using axios in a nuxt plugin: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage/#-shortcuts, hence i was in confusion.