# Typescript extend HTTP Response interface

Tags: node.js, typescript

So I have the following code using `axios` library:

```
const BTrustURLResponse: Response = await axios.get(`${process.env.BTRUST_URL}/flow/${process.env.BTRUST_FLOWID}/link?callback_url=${callback_url}`, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.BTRUST_API_KEY}`,
    },
});
```

I know for sure (`console.log(Object.keys(BTrustURLResponse))`) that the returned object has property `data`. But as default `Response` interface does not include `data` property.

How can I fix it?

I've tried the following:

1. Created `@types` directory, with `response` directory, then: [image]

And this is the file itself:

```
 declare global {
    export interface Response {
        data?: string,
    }
}
```

2. Then I did in `tsconfig.json` the following:`"typeRoots": ["@types", "./node_modules/@types"]`

But still I could not use `.data` with the `Response`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use a type for the response from axios.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57629111/how-to-use-a-type-for-the-response-from-axios-get)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create a separate @types file for creating a `Response` interface. Axios has a generic interface named `AxiosResponse<T>` which takes the `T` generic variable from `get<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R>;`.. Then that `T` generic var is used for `data` property of the `AxiosResponse`

see this:

```
interface ResponseData{
  _id?: string
  //... or any "property" you wanna add
}

const BTrustURLResponse = await axios.get<RespnseData>(`${process.env.BTRUST_URL}/flow/${process.env.BTRUST_FLOWID}/link?callback_url=${callback_url}`, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.BTRUST_API_KEY}`,
    },
});
```

Hope it works...

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/axios/axios  documentation looks like `data: {}` is an object but you are using string as the type for data object. `data?: string`, This could be an issue.
If you don't know the structure of your response then as a starting can use `data?: any` , if that works then you can give a proper type of your `data` object.